# Python Pandas - Computing stats on TimeSeriesIndexedData for each customer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

```
    UsageDate               CustID1  CustID2   .... CustIDn
0   2018-01-01 00:00:00     1.095
1   2018-01-01 01:00:00     1.129
2   2018-01-01 02:00:00     1.165
3   2018-01-01 04:00:00     1.697
. 
.
m   2018-31-01 23:00:00     1.835                     (m,n)
```

The dataframe (df) has m rows and n columns. m is a Hourly TimeSeries Index which starts from first hour of month to last hour of month. 
The columns are the customers which are almost 100,000.
The values at each cell of Dataframe are energy consumption values.

For every customer, I need to calculate:
1) Mean of every hour usage - so basically average of 1st hour of every day in a month, 2nd hour of every day in a month etc.

2) Summation of usage of every customer

3) Top 3 usage hours - for a customer x, it can be "2018-01-01 01:00:00",
"2018-11-01 05:00:00" "2018-21-01 17:00:00"

4) Bottom 3 usage hours - Similar explanation as above

5) Mean of usage for every customer in the month

My main point of trouble is how to aggregate data both for every customer and the hour of day, or day together.

For summation of usage for every customer, I tried:
`df_temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=["TotalUsage"])`

`for col in df.columns:`

```
`df_temp[col,"TotalUsage"] = df[col].apply.sum()`
```

However, this and many version of this which I tried are not helping me solve the problem.

Please help me with an approach and how to think about such problems.

Also, since the dataframe is large, it would be helpful if we can talk about Computational Complexity and how can we decrease computation time.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [pandas.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

(I didn't test the code because I didn't have a good sample dataset from which to work. If there are errors, let me know.)

For some of your requirements, you'll need to add a column with the hour:

```
 df['hour']=df['UsageDate'].dt.hour
```

1) Mean by hour.

```
 mean_by_hour=df.groupby('hour').mean()
```

2) Summation by user.

```
 sum_by_uers=df.sum()
```

3) Top usage by customer. Bottom 3 usage hours - Similar explanation as above.--I don't quite understand your desired output, you might be asking too many different questions in this question. If you want the hour and not the value, I think you may have to iterate through the columns. Adding an example may help.

4) Same comment.

5) Mean by customer.

```
mean_by_cust = df.mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is all the information you are looking for but it will point you in the right direction:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data for 3 days
np.random.seed(1)
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods= 72, freq='H'), columns=['UsageDate'])
data2  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(72,5), columns=[f'ID_{i}' for i in range(5)])
df = data.join([data2])
# print('Sample Data:')
# print(df.head())
# print()

# mean of every month and hour per year
# groupby year month hour then find the mean of every hour in a given year and month
mean_data = df.groupby([df['UsageDate'].dt.year, df['UsageDate'].dt.month, df['UsageDate'].dt.hour]).mean()
mean_data.index.names = ['UsageDate_year', 'UsageDate_month', 'UsageDate_hour']
# print('Mean Data:')
# print(mean_data.head())
# print()

# use set_index with max and head
top_3_Usage_hours = df.set_index('UsageDate').max(1).sort_values(ascending=False).head(3)
# print('Top 3:')
# print(top_3_Usage_hours)
# print()

# use set_index with min and tail
bottom_3_Usage_hours = df.set_index('UsageDate').min(1).sort_values(ascending=False).tail(3)
# print('Bottom 3:')
# print(bottom_3_Usage_hours)
```

out:

```
Sample Data:
            UsageDate      ID_0      ID_1      ID_2      ID_3      ID_4
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.417022  0.720324  0.000114  0.302333  0.146756
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00  0.092339  0.186260  0.345561  0.396767  0.538817
2 2018-01-01 02:00:00  0.419195  0.685220  0.204452  0.878117  0.027388
3 2018-01-01 03:00:00  0.670468  0.417305  0.558690  0.140387  0.198101
4 2018-01-01 04:00:00  0.800745  0.968262  0.313424  0.692323  0.876389

Mean Data:
                                                   ID_0      ID_1      ID_2  \
UsageDate_year UsageDate_month UsageDate_hour                                 
2018           1               0               0.250716  0.546475  0.202093   
                               1               0.414400  0.264330  0.535928   
                               2               0.335119  0.877191  0.380688   
                               3               0.577429  0.599707  0.524876   
                               4               0.702336  0.654344  0.376141   

                                                   ID_3      ID_4  
UsageDate_year UsageDate_month UsageDate_hour                      
2018           1               0               0.244185  0.598238  
                               1               0.400003  0.578867  
                               2               0.623516  0.477579  
                               3               0.429835  0.510685  
                               4               0.503908  0.595140  

Top 3:
UsageDate
2018-01-01 21:00:00    0.997323
2018-01-03 23:00:00    0.990472
2018-01-01 08:00:00    0.988861
dtype: float64

Bottom 3:
UsageDate
2018-01-01 19:00:00    0.002870
2018-01-03 02:00:00    0.000402
2018-01-01 00:00:00    0.000114
dtype: float64
```

For top and bottom 3 if you want to find the min sum across rows then:

```
df.set_index('UsageDate').sum(1).sort_values(ascending=False).tail(3)
```